# Zend Framework Plugin for Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, eclipse-pdt

I have eclipse PDT IDE version 1.2.0 installed. I have used it together with Dojo to develop very interesting Ajax applications. Now i want to enable the Zend framework within my eclipse IDE. How can i do this. After some googling, i have tried the following.

1.) downloaded the Zend framework and unzipped to my C directory.
2.) added the following path in my php.ini file

include_path = ".;C:\ZendFramework-1.10.5\library"

3.) changed the following line in the httpd.conf file in Apache to support .htaccess files

AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

Restart Apache once and tested to see if this had any effect. I tested by trying to create a new PHP project and take a look at the structure of the project files.

The question is

1.) how can i include zend framework to an already existing eclipse pdt ide.

2.) is there a plugin that can be added directly or can i use the add software capabilities of eclipse. If yes, what URL do i have to supply for software download

3.) finally, how do i test to make sure that the zend framework has been properly installed

thanks for your help

Answer (score 15):

I suggest setting ZF path as library for your ide (Preferences > PHP > PHP Libraries > New > Add External Folder). And then for your project: RMB on project in sidebar > Properties > PHP Include Path > Add Library > User Library > select your library.

I develop full time in Zend and this way is the best so far ;) (if you don't want to pay for ZendStudio ;)

Comment: BTW You don't HAVE TO set include path in php.ini. Your app bootstrap can set the paths too. Consult the manual quicstart (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

Comment: The pic in the first link is missing.

Comment: Chris: I replaced it with text ;)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can add references to the Zend Framework to any project in Eclipse by configuring its include path.

2) I'd say that most of the custom Zend support built for Eclipse has gone into Zend Studio For Eclipse, from the folks at Zend. Of course, that costs money, but you're able to download and play with it for free. Of course, once you have ZF in your project's include path, it will show up in code completion and documentation snippets, etc.

3) Try using require_once on something in the Zend Framework folder. If you get an error, your PHP include path isn't properly set up.

Comment: thanks for your reply

I have included the Zend library in the PHP Include Path and i have configured the include_path in php.ini to point to this library. All of this in an existing php project.

Now how can i test that the library is properly installed. 

I already took a look at the Zend Studio for eclipse and as you say, it cost money, so it is not an option for me. Thanks once more

Comment: Because it's a class library, there's not really anything like "Make test" or what not. Because all of the Zend Framework library is together, being able to include one component means you should be fine to use the autoloader and be able to call any of them.