# Eclipse PDT autocomplete current project not working

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-pdt

i just tried to enable autocomplete Zend library in my Eclipse project, following this post => [Zend Framework Plugin for Eclipse PDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085030/zend-framework-plugin-for-eclipse-pdt) , looks like it worked a while yesterday, then i shotdown my computer, and this morning, the only autocomplete i could get is the PhpCore one !
I restarted my computer 3 times, i clean my project too, and nothing change, and my project and my Zend library can be seen in my PHP Include path.

I just can't figure out what's going on, if anybody have a hint, it would be really great

PS: my IDE is the Helios Service Release 2 (Eclipse for php version 1.3.2)

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues had a very similar problem which he resolved by creating a new eclipse workspace and re-importing the project. Another possible solution would be to run the eclipse workspace cleaner (run `eclipse.exe --clean`). If none of these approaches work, you may wish to consider raising a defect against Zend.

Comment: Well, i did try to do as you said, but that didn't solve my problem, and, next and even get another problem with Eclipse meaning each time i tried to work with, it used 100% of my CPU, and freezing,...
So i give up and downloaded Aptana and, until now it worked fine, even if i didn't get all the functionnalities like by exemple the Zend Framework antocomplete